# Trying to bring a bike on amtrak?

Tags: trains, bicycles, amtrak

I'm hoping to bring my bike with me on Amtrak from Syracuse, NY to the Albany, NY station. I feel like I have seen bike cars on Amtrak before but according to this article, bikes aren't allowed (http://maphappy.org/2015/03/things-that-will-get-you-kicked-off-amtrak/). I was wondering if there were any of you guys who have had personal experience w/ this topic (seeing someone get kicked out of Amtrak for carrying a bike, attempting to bring your own bike on Amtrak, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Well you most likely won't get kicked off because of the bicycle unless you just bring it on board without permission.

According to the [Amtrak Policy](http://www.amtrak.com/bring-your-bicycle-onboard) there are a few routes that offer "walk-on" bicycle service but none of them travel through Albany.

You can reserve space on the bicycle rack or put it into baggage in Syracuse and pick it up in Albany, so I would just suggest doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Regular bicycles take up a lot of space, are unbalanced, can't stack, and their pedals are ankle eaters. Unless they have a designated space, they are a hazard.

That said, if you pack your bike in a suitcase or carrying case, so that is the same size and shape as airplane checked luggage, you should be fine. This is what I do with my folding bike. When asked what it is, I say that it's exercise equipment.